# Error trying to generate token using .NET JWT library

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I'm trying to use package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to generate a token. I found some code samples online, was pretty straightforward, but then I'm running into an error that I can't figure out. Here's the code I'm using (has been modified slightly for brevity):

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Reflection" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IdentityModel.Tokens" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Claims" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust" %>

<script runat="server">
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static string GetJwtToken()
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var input = "anyoldrandomtext";
            var securityKey = new byte[input.Length * sizeof(char)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(input.ToCharArray(), 0, securityKey, 0, securityKey.Length);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                new Claim( ClaimTypes.UserData,
                "IsValid", ClaimValueTypes.String, "(local)" )
              }),
                TokenIssuerName = "self",
                AppliesToAddress = "https://www.mywebsite.com",
                Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, now.AddMinutes(60)),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey),
                  "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
                  "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"),
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return tokenString;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I keep getting the following error at line 113 (var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);):

*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor' to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor'*

But I've seen many examples online doing things exactly as I've done them. I also ran into this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089(v=vs.110).aspx) that states the following:

> In WIF 3.5, all of the WIF classes were contained in the
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel assembly
>   (microsoft.identitymicrosoft.identitymodel.dll). In WIF 4.5, the WIF
>   classes have been split across the following assemblies: mscorlib
>   (mscorlib.dll), System.IdentityModel (System.IdentityModel.dll),
>   System.IdentityModel.Services (System.IdentityModel.Services.dll), and
>   System.ServiceModel (System.ServiceModel.dll).
>
> The WIF 3.5 classes were all contained in one of the
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel namespaces; for example,
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens,
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web, and so on. In WIF 4.5, the WIF classes
>   are now spread across the System.IdentityModel namespaces, the
>   System.Security.Claims namespace, and the System.ServiceModel.Security
>   namespace. In addition to this reorganization, some WIF 3.5 classes
>   have been dropped in WIF 4.5.

I tried for debugging sake to switch to use the Microsoft.* namespace for the SecurityTokenDescriptor, and then I get another series of errors saying TokenIssuerName, AppliesToAddress, and Lifetime aren't valid properties for that class. Yet when I look at the docs online, seems like those properties do exist on Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor. Yet in my Visual Studio, when I do Go to Definition for that class, they're not there, leading me to believe that there's some kind of configuration issue in my Visual Studio. In my package manager, it shows I have Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens v5.0.0 installed. I also changed the project to .NET framework 4.5.1 since the JWT library requires it. Beyond that, I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation with the OpenID Connect library when I upgraded, which previously was in the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions` package (which depended on 4.0.2 of the JWT package) but now is `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` which depends on 2.0.0 of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols` (which depends on 5.0.0 of the JWT package).

Remove any of your `Microsoft.IdentityModel*` and `System.IdentityModel*` packages, and install only the latest (5.0.0) `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package which depends on `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`.

You'll want using statements for these namespaces:

- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (but not System.IdentityModel.Tokens)
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
- System.Security.Claims

Microsoft has simplified some of the parameters to be more like what you would expect from other platforms' JWT libraries, so the `SecurityTokenDescriptor` properties are a little different:

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim( ClaimTypes.UserData,
        "IsValid", ClaimValueTypes.String, "(local)" )
    }),
    Issuer = "self",
    Audience = "https://www.mywebsite.com",
    Expires = now.AddMinutes(60),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
};
```

Note that `SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256` is a string constant for "HS256", just like you'd use in most other libraries.  Using the above code plus the example in your question, you should be able to generate a valid JWT.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this and it worked beautifully. Many thanks!