# Looking for an accurate, current, how-to for doing JWT in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

There seems to be some historical tangle between **System**.IdentityModel.Tokens and **Microsoft**.IdentityModel.Tokens namespaces.  I've spent a day trying to find documentation that matches the IdentityModel objects I find, and cannot.

I am trying to set up my Web API project to use JWT tokens, and am looking to the Microsoft documentation, especially for [the TokenValidationParameters object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters(v=vs.114).aspx) which they say belongs to the System.IdentityModel.Tokens namespace.

But it does not. I have System.IdentityModel.Tokens properly referenced in my project, got the latest from Nuget, etc., but the object is just not there.

However I *do* find such an object inside the "**Microsoft**.IdentityModel.Tokens" namespace -- but it doesn't have the properties that I see in various how-to sites, like these:

- Microsoft code:
  code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Native-App-to-REST-de57f2cc/sourcecode?fileId=96343&pathId=697488104
- Otherwise great site:   markwalsh.io/development/2014/12/02/ASP.Net%20Web%20API%20with%20JWT/

These sites reference the non-existent "System" object, and use properties that the "Microsoft" one doesn't possess, like "SigningToken" and "AllowedAudience."

All the documentation and how-to's I find focus on the System.IdentityModel.Tokens namespace, which is unusable because the objects in it don't exist.

SO: Can someone point me to a good how-to reference for doing JWT in Web API, that *uses the **Microsoft**.IdentityModel.Tokens namespace?*

I have lost a day to this, and would appreciate the help.

Follow-up question:  Do I need this project configured for OWIN for this to all suddenly work?  I can barely find a mention of JWT in Web API that doesn't automatically presume you're doing OWIN.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. A pointer to a *good how-to reference* would be an off-site resource. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Ken, you are 100% right.  I suppose I was more frustrated than I knew.  I don't know that I _could_ have recast it as a valid SO question, so I was out of bounds.

And thanks for saying so politely and cordially.  I've seen the flames that can go up over this kind of thing...

Comment: You're [not the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231321/error-trying-to-generate-token-using-net-jwt-library) suffering, it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither tokens worked for me as they seem to be geared for OWIN and "DotNetOpenAuth"

[JWT](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt) may be a good reference to role your own solution or simply copy JWT.cs into your project

[OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#jwt) site has some other C# references for JWT

Comment: Steve, thanks.  Your pointer towards JWT-DotNet was ultimately what I used.  I decided to back away from the debris of Microsoft's various starts-and-stops around ASP.NET these past few years.  (v5.0, no wait! vNext! No, wait, OWIN!  Okay, really Katana, but we'll name everything OWIN!" but hang on, _brainstorm!_  Core  v1.0!)  I know it will all settle down into something brilliant, but it was making me nuts.  JWT-DotNet just keeps it simple.